# how to vectorize an expression in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I'm unable to vectorize this :

```
for x=2:i
   for y=2:j
     if(x ~= y)
       Savings(x,y) = Costs(x,1) + Costs(1,y) - Costs(x,y);
     end
   end
end
```

Could someone tell me of I could improve the performance of this code ? Thanks

Comment: just a small thing here: try not to use i and j as indices. You will find much information about this issue here at SO!

Comment: and well, I just see, that you are not using i as an indice but as a variable, what will lead to the same problem anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize it like this, I don't know if that will effect your performance or not though. You will need to test that yourself.

```
m=size(Costs, 1);
n=size(Costs, 2);

[Y, X] = meshgrid(2:m, 2:n);

Cx = Costs(:,1);
Cy = Costs(1,:);

S = Cx(X) + Cy(Y) - Costs(2:end,2:end);

S(eye(m-1,n-1)==1) = 0;
Savings = zeros(m,n);
Savings(2:end,2:end) = S;
```

**EDIT**

Incidentally I have verified that all three methods give the same answer. For a `Costs` size of 400x400 the run times are were as follows:

```
Elapsed time is 0.00741386 seconds. //My method
Elapsed time is 0.003304 seconds.   //Mohsen's method (after correcting to prevent errors)
Elapsed time is 2.16231 seconds.    //Original Loop
```

So both our methods give a significant boost. However if you just pre-allocate `Savings` your loop is actually the fastest. Is this really too slow for your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

With some help from `bsxfun`:

```
Ix=2:i; 
Iy=2:j;
I = false(i,j);
I(Ix,Iy) = bsxfun(@ne, Ix', Iy);
S = bsxfun(@plus, Costs(Ix,1), Costs(1,Iy)) - Costs(Ix,Iy);
Savings(I) = S(I(Ix,Iy));
```

Comment: `I1` and `I2` are undefined?

Comment: @Dan Thanks! I renamed `I1` and `I2` to `Ix` and `Iy` but forgot in one crucial lien :-)

Comment: You also need to make these changes: `Savings(I) = S(I(2:end, 2:end));` followed by
`Savings = reshape([Savings, 0], m,n);` then your method gives the same result as mine (slightly faster) but both a vastly faster than the original loop

Comment: @Dan Thanks again. Corrected the indexing of `I`, but I don't see the reason behind `reshape`

Comment: When I tried it I got a vector that was missing the last value. Did you pre-allocate `Savings` maybe?

Comment: Yes, i preallocated Savings = zeros(i,j)